# Pandas: Setting values in GroupBy doesn't affect original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, pandas-groupby

```
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
As = data.groupby('A')
for name, group in As:
    current_column = group.iloc[:, i]
    current_column.iloc[0] = np.NAN
```

The problem: 'data' stays the same after this loop, even though I'm trying to set values to np.NAN .

Comment: what are you trying to do? No, this is not going to work because groupby generates a copy of the data.

Comment: Group the data by some column (Let's say look at each country differently), than edit the data of each country differently .

Comment: What is the nature of your "edits"?

Comment: Data cleansing.

Comment: Okay, define some function `f`, clean your data inside `f`, and then pass `f` to `groupby.apply`.

Comment: I saw an example, but how do I pass parameters to f ?
    def f(x, index):
        return x.....
    group.apply(f) # want to edit group by index

Comment: `def f(x): ... ; return y # x and y are dataframes`

Answer (score 1):

As @ohduran suggested:

```
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
As = data.groupby('A')
new_data = pd.DataFrame()
for name, group in As:
    # edit grouped data
    # eg group.loc[:,'column'] = np.nan
    new_data = new_data.append(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

.groupby() does not change the initial DataFrame. You might want to store what you do with groupby() on a different variable, and the accumulate it in a different DataFrame using that for loop?

Comment: That's what I also tried, after the above code, I also did:
    united_group = pd.DataFrame(
    for name, group in As:
        united_group = united_group.append(group)

Comment: Why not creating different Series that you can then merge using concat()?

`s1 = pd.Series([1, 2], index=['A', 'B'], name='s1')
s2 = pd.Series([3, 4], index=['A', 'B'], name='s2')
pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)`